# Inconsistent 2D collision resolution

Tags: c++, 2d, game-physics, sfml

I'm currently making a platforming game with SFML, and I'm having inconsistencies with my collisions resolution.  I'm using AABB for collision detection, my collision resolution code is below (I'm only trying colliding with the floor for now)

```
if (_player.collider.center.y < _entity.collider.center.y)
    {
        _player.vel.y = 0;
        _player.onGround = true;
    }
```

_entity is whatever block the player collided with, and when onGround is true, gravity for the player is turned off.

The when my player initially falls onto the block, he is clipped slightly into the block, however when I jump, he lands correctly (most of the time).

Is this the best way to go about collision resolution? Or is there a more effective way?

Answer (score 0):

After you detect a collision, it's not enough to simply set velocity and other booleans to the necessary value, you must also correct the collision.

What probably happened is that before your code detected a collision, your player was slightly above an entity, and after the next frame, the player's velocity was high enough that it caused a clipping into the entity, and only after that is where your game detected the collision. And on other occasions, the velocity may have aligned perfectly in that the game prevented a clipping or was close enough that it appears as if the player is not clipped into another entity.

Additionally, I don't think using `center.y` is a good idea, since it will be off due to truncation.

Comment: Would it be better to set the position to the previous position before the collision? Or would this result in the same issue?

Comment: @slinky55 No, that is not enough, since it may be that the point before the collision is not where the player should be after collision correction. Let's say that your player is 6 pixels above the ground, and on the next frame, the player is 2 pixels below ground. If you detect the collision 2 pixels into the ground and revert the player back to 6 pixels above ground, this isn't where the player is supposed to be, the player is supposed to be standing on the ground.